# Multi-Dimensional String Arrays

Tags: python, arrays

Trying to develop a text based Hangman game in Python and want to use multi arrays to hold the words to guess but separated into individual letters.

I'm currently getting this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`.

Any ideas?

```
 words = [['d', 'u', 'c', 'k'],
      [],
      [],
      [],
      []]
```

My thought would be that if I ask to print array 1, 1 then I would get back `"d"`?

Comment: The code you posted does not exhibit this error.

Comment: Also just and FYI. In python they lists not arrays which are different as there are numpy arrays and a different `array` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i ask to print array 1, 1 then i would get back "d"?

No that would return an error, as arrays start at 0.

So you must return words[0][0], that would get you back "d".

Answer (score 0):

Index your list as `words[j][i]` instead of `words[i, j]`